# bitcoin transaction denied

Tags: bitcoin-core

I am waiting for a transaction from Dec 13 to get denied by the blockchain and be able to use the funds again. How long does that usually take? I have tried multiple transaction accelerators both free and paid and nothing has helped at all. I am using Mycelium wallet , have tried deleting that transaction and reloading my wallet from 0 and it keeps coming back, tried using the verification phrase to open the wallet on another device and same thing. How long will this take? It's about $250 and I can use the money. I tried CPFP but Mycelium says can't do it, and the receiving end is a Coinbase account and that won't allow it either. Any help would be appreciated. If anyone is able to have it accelerated successfully I will be glad to tip.

Thanks

Comment: duplicate of https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it?noredirect=1&lq=1

if you were actually using bitcoin-core as per your tag, it'd be easy with -zapwallettxes. I've used that even after only 24 hours and been able to resend the transactions.

Comment: Did you rebroadcast the transaction? Because the transaction got accepted into blockchain.info's mempool 03.01.18 . It takes AT LEAST 2 week for a transaction to be dropped if you are lucky(based on Bitcoin Core default settings). But most likely it will float for weeks/months. Do you have the transaction ID, may be useful considering available options.